# Getting wrong contentType from EML attachment

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using Microsoft Graph to fetch mail and I recently noticed when an email has a `.eml` attachment, there are two cases:

1. If the sender attach that email through drugging emails to the composer, the attachment will be an item attachment type. <-- I can handle this case
2. If the sender attaches a `.eml` file through clicking "attach file", that attachment will be a type of file attachment. Up to this point, I think it is fine to be a file attachment. But when I try to fetch that attachment, the attachment content type is `application/octet-stream` which is wrong. Shouldn't it be `message/rfc822`? With `application/octet-stream`, I cannot create that attachment from our server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't wrong, `application/octet-stream` simply represents a generic/unknown binary file. From [RFC 2046 § 4.5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1):

> The "octet-stream" subtype is used to indicate that a body contains arbitrary binary data.

Your application can make its own determination on how to handle the file. In this case, the `.eml` is just a text file. You can simply fetch the attachment and treat it as raw text.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Marc! But if there are other application/octet-stream attachments, how can I make that determination between eml and those other  application/octet-stream attachments?

Comment: The file extension should be `.eml`

Comment: Make sense! Thanks!